# latitude and longitude detail by dragging marker on google place map doesn't working after search from search map box

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am working on [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hq0b49/1/).Where initially i am able to get latitude and  longitude on marker dragging but after search from search box  when new result come with new location marker i am unable to get latitude and longitude with this marker.

Below is my code....

```js
$(function () {
         var lat = 44.88623409320778,
             lng = -87.86480712897173,
             latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

         //zoomControl: true,
         //zoomControlOptions: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,

         var mapOptions = {
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
             zoom: 13,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
             panControl: true,
             panControlOptions: {
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
             },
             zoomControl: true,
             zoomControlOptions: {
                 style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
             }
         },
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               draggable: true,
                position: latlng,
                 map: map,
        });

        //  var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');


        //  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
        //      types: ["geocode"]
        //  });

        //  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
        //  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        //  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (event) {
        //      infowindow.close();
        //      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        //      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        //          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        //      } else {
        //          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        //          map.setZoom(17);
        //      }

             // moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
        //      $('.MapLat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
        //      $('.MapLon').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
        //  });
        // google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
        //  $('.MapLat').val(event.latLng.lat());
        //  $('.MapLon').val(event.latLng.lng());
        //     document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
        //     document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
        //      infowindow.close();
        //              var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        //              geocoder.geocode({
        //                  "latLng":event.latLng
        //              }, function (results, status) {
        //                  console.log(results, status);
        //                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        //                      console.log(results);
        //                      var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
        //                          lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
        //                          placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
        //                          latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        //                      moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
        //                      $("#searchTextField").val(results[0].formatted_address);
        //                  }
        //              });
        // });
// *****************************
var markers = [];
         var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (input));

    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {

        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        }

        markers = [];
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

            // Create a marker for each place.
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
            draggable:true,
                title: place.name,
                position: latlng,
            });

            markers.push(marker);

            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
           marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             draggable: true,
            position: place.geometry.location,
           map: map,
        });
        }

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });


     var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, {
             types: ["geocode"]
         });

         autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

         google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (event) {
             infowindow.close();
             var place = searchBox.getPlace();
             if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                 map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
             } else {
                 map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                 map.setZoom(17);
             }

             moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
             $('.MapLat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
             $('.MapLon').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
         });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
         $('.MapLat').val(event.latLng.lat());
         $('.MapLon').val(event.latLng.lng());
            document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
             infowindow.close();
                     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                     geocoder.geocode({
                         "latLng":event.latLng
                     }, function (results, status) {
                         console.log(results, status);
                         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                             console.log(results);
                             var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                                 lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                                 placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                                 latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                             moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                             $("#pac-input").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                         }
                     });
        });

// ****************************
        
         function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
          console.log(latlng);
             marker.setPosition(latlng);
             infowindow.setContent(placeName);
             //infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }
     });
```

```css
#map-canvas {
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
}
.controls {
    margin-top: 16px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    width: 400px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
    width: 401px;
}
.pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=uk&language=en&sensor=true"></script>


<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<br>
            latitude:<input name="latitude" class="MapLat" value="" type="text" placeholder="Latitude" style="width: 161px;" disabled>
            longitude:<input name="longitude" class="MapLon" value="" type="text" placeholder="Longitude" style="width: 161px;" disabled>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 350px;width: 500px;margin: 0.6em;"></div>
```

Pasted 3 minutes ago — Expires in 7 days

Comment: You don't have any code to retrieve the lat/lng of the marker(s) when dragged.   I'm not going to repeat my list of links to questions that show how to do that... Where do you see the "result is always null"? How are you expecting it to work if the search returns more than one result?  Only put one on the map?  Output the latitude and longitude of the last marker dragged? Something else?

Comment: same problem...does anybody know how to do????